# How to change the text permanently using android

Tags: android

i have changed the button text loaded from the EditText in android.but when relaunched the app it does not changed the text it show the first one.for example a button with text first i changed it loaded from Edittext of second but when relaunch the app it show the first not the second.Please help   me.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: This is because your application when closed all its data will be wiped off from RAM and causing you to lose the information. This is how a system should work and it is. Whenever you want the data get it back even after restart, you need to store it on persistent storage. Refer here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store `EditText` value and set that value to `Button` at the time of Re launching.

**To store value :**

```
SharedPreferences p=getSharedPreferences("data",MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit=p.edit();
edit.putString("value",yourEditText.getText().toString());
edit.commit();
```

**To get value :**

```
 String value=p.getString("value",null);
 if(value!=null)
     yourEditText.setText(value);
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use some form of persistent storage. Any changes made to button text etc, during execution actually happen in the RAM and only for that execution. If you want the changes to be "permanent" over multiple launches, you would need to set up some information in the storage and use that to fill your button text upon start-up of the app.